# Is the activation function the only difference between logistic regression and perceptron?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification

As far as I know, [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) can be denoted as:

$$
f(x) = \sigma(w \cdot x + b)
$$

A [perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron)  can be denoted as:

$$
f(x) = \operatorname{sign} (w \cdot x + b)
$$

It seems that the only difference between logistic regression and a perceptron model is the activation function.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: Yes and No; they're both similar decision function models but there's more to each model than their main formulation**

One could use the `logit` function as the activation function of a `perceptron` and consider the output a probability.  Yet, that value would likely need a probability calibration.

As with most ML models several things are very similar from model to model, on the other hand varying tiny parameters can result in a different model.  Let's take on both sides:

### `Logit` Regression and `Perceprton` *similarities*

The `logit` function is used in `logit` regression for its properties of being an *S-curve*, by default valued between 0 and 1.  The `sign` activation function in the `perceptron` is also *shaped like* an "S-curve" (with very rough edges - so mathematically not an S-curve by its definition but with similar properties) valued "between" -1 and 1.  Another activation function often used with `perceptron` is hyperbolic tangent (`tanh`), which is another *S-curve* - very similar to the `sign` function but with a rounded shape (and also valued between -1 and 1).  We can say that `tanh` is similar to `sign` because:

$$
\texttt{sign}(x) \approx \texttt{tanh}(kx) \qquad \text{for k >> 0}\\
or\\
\texttt{sign}(x) = \texttt{tanh}(kx) \qquad k \to \infty
$$

So it makes sense to compare `tanh` with `logit` as an analogy to compare `sign` with `logit`.

Now the `logit` function is (the one used in logistic regression that is - not the statistical $ln(x/(1- x))$ one):

$$
\texttt{logit}(x) = \frac{L}{1 + e^{-k(x - b)}}
$$

Where $L$, $k$ and $b$ are parameters that we can steer. (Since $b$ is a bias term, an unknown constant, it does not matter if we write $- b$ or $b$)

And the hyperbolic tangent is:

$$
\texttt{tanh}(x) = \frac{e^{2x} - 1}{e^{2x} + 1}
$$

But wait, if we set the parameters of the `logit` as $L = 1$, $k = 1$ and $b = 0$, then:

$$
2 \cdot \texttt{logit}(2x) - 1 = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{1 + e^{-2x}} -1
= \frac{2e^{2x}}{e^{2x} + 1} - 1
= \frac{2e^{2x}}{e^{2x} + 1} - \frac{e^{2x} + 1}{e^{2x} + 1}
= \frac{2e^{2x} - e^{2x} - 1}{e^{2x} + 1}
= \frac{e^{2x} - 1}{e^{2x} + 1} = \texttt{tanh}(x)
$$

So `tanh`, which is more-or-less a rounded `sign`, is a scaled and shifted special case of `logit`.  *Not only the model differ by the activation function alone but the activation functions are very similar to each other*.

### Logit Regression and Perceprton *differences*

#### Log probabilities (this is probably the major difference and the most important one)

We looked at the `logit` function above but in reality the `logit` regression takes **the logarithm of the `logit`** instead of plain values for the probabilities. Or, more exactly, in statistics the `logit` is defined as the natural logarithm of what in most ML implementations is defined as a `logit` decision function. This is very different from the `perceptron` which performs the **output directly from the activation function**.

#### Regularization

Both models (`logit` regression and `perceptron`) are often trained with some form of gradient descent optimizer (be it SGD, have it momentum, or even something else). This training will optimize all parameters ($w$ in your representation or $k$ in mine for `logit` and the weights in a `perceptron`) but the model itself will also be given a bunch of *hyper-parameters*.  And in terms of hyper-parameters things do differ:

The `perceptron` will be trained by optimizing the weights (including a bias) and can be regularized with $L_2$ or $L_1$ (or a combination of both). One may or may not add a bias term.

The actual model of the logistic regression will optimize the logarithm but there's more: most implementations will include a scaling hyper-parameter ($C$) which will multiply the log probabilities. One can use $C$ to regularize the model apart from $L_1$ and/or $L_2$.

#### Multi-class

The `perceptron` is always a binary classifier.  One sets an output threshold and that works as the decision function (for the `sign` or `tanh` functions the threshold is often $0$). For multi-class classification one must build One-Vs-Rest or One-Vs-One groups of models.

Logistic Regression can be used as a binary classifier and in this case can be used for multi-class classification with One-Vs-Rest and One-Vs_one methods. But, there exist a formulation of logistic regression for direct multi-class classification:

$$
\texttt{multinomial logit}(x|y) = \frac{e^{-k_y(x - b)}}{\sum^{K}_{k=0} e^{-c(x - b)}} \qquad \text{for y in }\{0,1,\dots\}
$$

i.e. whether $x$ belongs to class $y$. This is performed for each class and the result can be passed to a `softmax` function.  This multi-class formulation can be performed because `logit` regression deals with log probabilities instead of direct inputs (contrary to a `perceptron`).

Comment: thanks for your answer. what does LT;DR stands for?

Comment: you are so kind, thank you so much. I guess `LT;DR` at the beginning of your answer means `TL;DR`, that is, `Too long;` but `please read`. Do I understand this right?

Comment: @Jay - oh that!  LT;DR -> too long; didn't read - on SO/SE it is used to indicate that the answer is long so here is a summary sentence - then i'll expand on it.  (therefore someone may read just that sentence and be blissfully ignorant of the details if he so wants).

Comment: thanks for your kindness and patience. Does the S curve in `The sign activation function in the perceptron is also an S curve (with very rough edges) valued "between" -1 and 1.` mean something else don't need to be differentiable in section 2? usually S curve does need to be differentiable.

Comment: @Jay - You are correct.  I guess the avoidance of writing S-curve by writing `S` curve is not a good enough distinction.  Clarified properly and added the s-curve notation.  And yep, `sign(x)` is definitely *not* differentiable.