# What are contexts where a perceptron model could be defined?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, activation-function, perceptron

per this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/53476/73919), a perceptron could use the logit function as the activation function.

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron)

> In the context of neural networks, a perceptron is an artificial
>   neuron using the Heaviside step function as the activation function.

so, a perceptron does no have to use Heaviside step function as the activation function.

besides neural networks, what are other contexts where a perceptron is defined and would use other activation functions.

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by "context"?

Comment: neural networks is a context where a perceptron model could be defined.