# Could perceptron use the standard logistic function as its activation function?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, data-mining

the [perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) is an algorithm for supervised learning of binary classifiers. A binary classifier is a function which can decide whether or not an input, represented by a vector of numbers, belongs to some specific class.

per this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/53476/73919), a perceptron could use some other functions as its activation function.

The standard logistic function is the logistic function with parameters (k = 1, x0 = 0, L = 1) which yields

${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}f(x)&={\frac {1}{1+e^{-x}}}={\frac {e^{x}}{e^{x}+1}}={\tfrac {1}{2}}+{\tfrac {1}{2}}\tanh({\tfrac {x}{2}})\\\end{aligned}}}$

Could perceptron use the standard [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) as the activation function? if yes, what is the difference between `a perceptron with the standard logistic function` and logistic function